# Dynamically Created Input (type="file") and Form Elements

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to create an `input type="file"` so the user can upload multiple images and after uploading, I need thumnails of those pictures. In order to do that I created a Form element and its child an Input File Element in JavaScript.

I also need a multiple file browsing box.

How can I set the "action" attribute for the form through JS in order to get the php script?

```
var form = document.createElement("FORM");
second_plate.appendChild(form);
console.log(form);

var inputpic = document.createElement("INPUT");
form.appendChild(inputpic);
inputpic.setAttribute("type" , "file");
inputpic.setAttribute("class" , "inputpic");
```

Is there something I need to be aware of before doing that because I am completely new at uploading and browsing files.
If you could get me some reference for a good php script for what I need I would be much obliged.

PS: I prefer not using JQuery

Comment: Their are lot of things you need to do, But first I will say If you are new to PHP File Uploads then first thing, Don't try to generate element by javascript. It will only increase your learning time. First  google multiple file uploads in php (with some pre-defined upload number like 5). When you are comfortable with uploads using php then try dynamic generation  of form/element.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj Thank you for your answer and this is what i will do. But please tell me. Is it possible what i want beacuse in my app i need to generate it with js because the user will create a menu item from a text input and after clicking that menu item this upload input will be created

Comment: Yes Form and its child elements code can be generated through Javascript. But their are lot of things need to learn at their too. So I am suggesting first be comfortable with uploads with php. Then with javascript.